# meta title and meta description

Tags: meta-description

magento 2, magento automatically takes the meta title and meta description from the item name and item description. Is it advisable to leave it that way, or is it better to enter the meta title and meta description individually in search engine optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to SEO so better to enter value there as per SEO best practise. You can refer https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/meta-data.html for more information on meta data.